# My Unresolved Items are not visible

Tags: email, metadata, contact, tasks, event

I had to transfer all the data from an old Salesforce environment to a new one via the Data Loader but  on my new environment all the data such as Emails, Tasks etc is missing from My Unresolved Items.
 [image]

I'm looking for a solution of this issue, because the items are in the system, but they not appear in the right place the way they appear in the old environment.

Please advise how to make My Unresolved Items such as Tasks, Emials, Events, Contacts/Agents visible and available in my new prod enivronment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of what's "unresolved" can be related to workflow and "status". Since you did an import of the data, an workflow on the records won't be pending unless you've recreated the workflow or edited them again you recreated that workflow. The same would apply to items that have status picklists which relate those items to owners.

Equally important, I hope you uploaded the items in the proper order so they got related to the original records they referenced. Contacts after Accounts, Events after Contacts/Agents with Emails being last. All would need external ID's relating them to the proper records.